# Capture window Lat, Longs with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to figure out how to capture the four corners of a Leaflet window, so that I might load points based on where a user is zoomed in geographically. For example, have a look [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html).

Now, how would I capture the four corners of that view so that I could load only the points that are geometrically bounded to that general location - downtown London?

I have not been able to find any example for Leaflet specifically. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you should be searching with is called "bounds". Leaflet's `L.Map` has a method called `getBounds` which will return the bounds of the current mapview:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds

> Returns the LatLngBounds of the current map view.

It returns a `LatLngBounds` object which consist of a southwest and a northeast LatLng object:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds

> Represents a rectangular geographical area on a map.

How you use those bounds to query your points of interest from your server depends on the platform you are working with.

If you already have a dataset loaded and you want filter that based on the current bounds you could use `contains` method of the `LatLngBounds` object. You can use that to check if a point is contained within the current bounds:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains

> Returns true if the rectangle contains the given point.